# Call of Duty MW3 PS3 elite map packs transfering

Tags: call-of-duty-elite

Back when MW3 first came out me and my boyfriend bought the first elite map pack. Then our PS3 broke and we just now got a new one, and finally got WiFi again To play online.

How can one transfer the map pack to my new PS3? Also it's benefit so long since we bought the pack that I really don't remember how we did this. I think we typed in the redeem code or whatever. I know we did this on my boyfriend's profile, but it also downloaded onto my profile (same system obviously). Here's the catch: we cannot remember his password, we tried all the passwords we could remember.

Is there a way to transfer it from my account, even though it wasn't purchased from my profile?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Fallon Reed. I edited your question for clarity, and I'd just like to point out that the use of abbreviations (eg. "pls") and bad words is highly discouraged here. For a more through introduction to this site, check the [Site Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking if it's possible to just load the content from a subaccountt to the main account.

**No**, you can't do that unfortunately. The master account holds the power so if you're looking to reinstall content to the master account, the player must be logged in to the master account.

You may need to reset the password on the master account.

You can reset your PlayStation Network password and gain access to any DLC purchased and associated with that account. You'll need to at least remember the email account used to create the account to reset the password.

Sony has detailed [these](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/account/forgotpw.html) steps for you:

> To use this feature, you may be required to update the system
>   software.
>
> You can use the following method to reset your password if you forget
>   it.
>
> 1. Select  (PlayStation™Network) >  (Sign In).
> 2. Select [Forgot your password?] from the sign-in ID (e-mail address)
>      and password screen.
> 3. Enter your sign-in ID (e-mail address) and birth date
> 4. Reset your password using a PC.  An e-mail message is delivered to
>      the address that you used as your sign-in ID. Follow the steps in
>      the  e-mail message to reset your password using a PC.